# Android Studio floating action button's weird feature

Tags: android, button, background, action, floating-action-button

I am making my own android application and came across a weird issue. I've got a few floating action buttons into my app and in the editor they look just fine. But when I upload this app to my phone or to the simulator, an other strange color appears which even moves when I touch the button. ([the lighter blue is what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQXJK.png)).
What is this feature and how can I turn this off?
Thank you for your answers in advance.

Comment: This may be due to different theme used by the app. Please check if your theme in `xml` design layout is same as defined in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: You should also check the image asset, it might have a transparent-ish background.

Comment: share your code here